# ContentDocumentLink to get recently unshared FileIds for Files tab

Tags: rest-api, chatter, chatter-file, shared-activities

Whenever a File in files tab is updated (title renamed, description), ContentDocument field 'LastModifiedDate' is updated. For share activity on any file, ContentDocument's field 'LastReferencedDate' gets updated. So to get recently updated/shared fileIds, I am making following soql using Query API:

```
/services/data/v31.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ContentDocument+WHERE+LastModifiedDate>2015-05-08T09%3A26%3A16%2B00%3A00

/services/data/v31.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ContentDocument+WHERE+LastReferencedDate>2015-05-08T09%3A26%3A16%2B00%3A00
```

However, when an unshare activity happens, no field gets updated.

To get over the situation, I tried to use ContentDocumentLink standard object which holds sharing information. While trying to fetch unshare activities of a particular user as an Entity, I made following query:

```
/services/data/v32.0/queryAll?q=SELECT+ContentDocumentId,Id,IsDeleted,LinkedEntityId,ShareType,SystemModstamp,Visibility+FROM+ContentDocumentLink+WHERE+LinkedEntityId+=+'xx'+AND+IsDeleted+=+true
```

Keeping the 'IsDeleted'=true should return me the records that were deleted from this object and thus will reflect the unsharing activity with the LinkedEntityId specified. It is returning me 0 records every time proving that ContentDocumentLink records get hard-deleted.

Triggers are not possible on ContentDocumentLink object hence we cannot have 'before delete' trigger on it telling us about the unsharing activity. Also, push topics on ContentDocumentLink object is not possible.

I want to know is there any way I can fetch file Ids that are recently unshared using any API provided by salesforce?

chatter API calls to retrieve file sharing info are below which all needs fileIds to begin with:

```
/chatter/files/fileId
/chatter/files/batch/fileIds
```

Any help will be appreciated.